# Crossover algorithm for Travelling Salesman?

Tags: algorithm, genetic-algorithm, traveling-salesman, crossover

I am looking for a crossover algorithm for a genetic algorithm for the Travelling Salesman Problem.

However, my TSP problem is a variation of the traditional problem:

Instead of only being given a list of points that we need to visit, we are given a list points that we need to visit and a list of points we need to start at and end at. In other words, any route must start and end at any point belonging to the second list, but must visit all the points in the first list.

So in other words, not every permutation of points is valid. Because of this, I'm not sure if traditional crossover algorithms will work well (for instance, I tried ordered crossover and the children it created were generally worse than its parents).

Can anyone suggest a crossover algorithm?

Comment: Sounds more like the Vehicle Routing Problem than TSP.

Answer (score 0):

In order to maintain your crossover and mutation operators, you can add a repair operator that checks if the position of your starting and ending locations are correct and if they aren't, swap them into their valid positions (initial and ending).